# Installing PCRE 8+ on SLES SP3

Tags: software-installation, package-management, sles

I need to install PCRE 8+ on a Suse Enterprise Linux SP3 box.

The trouble is that the latest package available in the repo is 7.8.

How would I go about attaining 8+?

FYI, I need this to install The Bug Genie.

Comment: Found helpful answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18005152/270302

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the direct route would be to go to the PCRE website and download the package you want.

- http://www.pcre.org/

Or download from the SVN repo:

```
$ svn co svn://vcs.exim.org/pcre/code/trunk pcre
```

Since you're on SuSE you can probably go poking through the SuSE Build Service and get whatever version you need, or submit a build yourself. I found the PCRE `pcre.spec` file for 8.33.

- https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Factory/pcre/pcre.spec

Notice the links to things at the top of that URL. If you go poking around, say the [overview](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/openSUSE%3aFactory/pcre) page, from here are links to already built versions of PCRE. For example, under standard are RPMs for PCRE 8.33.

- https://build.opensuse.org/package/binaries/openSUSE:Factory/pcre?repository=standard

Comment: Sorry for the late reply on this one. The Build Service is the way to go. Coming from using apt-get to using rpm's behind an enterprise firewall is a bit of an adjustment. Build Service is awesome in this regard.